# How to improve my add class to element functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write a vanilla js function that works like jQuery's addClass() function. I have written the code below.

```
function checkType(value){ //get type of target
    var name = "";
    var type = value.split("");
    for(var i=1; i<type.length; i++){
        name = name + type[i];
    }
    if(type[0] == "#"){ //if id
        return document.getElementById(name);   //return id
    }else if(type[0] == "."){ //if class
        return document.getElementsByClassName(name); //return class
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

function classesToArray(value){ 
    if(value != null){
        value = value.split(" ");
        return value;
    }
    return [];
}

function addClass(target, value) {
    var element = checkType(target);
    var classes = classesToArray(value);
    if(element != null){
        classes.forEach(function(classItem){
            if(element.length){
                for(var i = 0; i < element.length; i++){
                    element[i].className += " " + classItem;
                }
            }else{
                element.className += " " + classItem;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So the way to use it is as below

```
addClass('.elementIdName','nameOfClassToAdd');    //target Id if begin with .
addClass('#elementClassName','nameOfClassToAdd'); //target className if begin with #

addClass('.elementIdName', 'nameOfClass1 nameOfClass2'); //you can also add multiple class names
```

The code works. But I know there's a lot of room to improve it. I'd really appreciate if someone could show me the ropes on what should I look for to improve this. Thanks

Comment: Requests for code improvement should be made on [CodeReview.se]. SO is for non-working code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to write your own addClass function.

You can use this:

```
let el = document.querySelector("#your_element_id");
if(el) {
   el.classList.add("your class name");
}
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: but the point of this is to handle the fallback browser as well considering classList is incompatible for IE 9 and below

Comment: @shrayder Trying to support IE9 and below is silly in this era. Even Microsoft hasn't supported IE9 for years. You will be bloating your code base with all sorts of polyfills to support an extremely tiny percentage of possible users. Just do some simple feature detection and tell users to use a more modern browser. IE9 also was the last version to support using IE special comments so you could insert elements only inside those comments and they only display in whatever version you want